# Computing the second fundamental form in the basis $\{T(s),N(s)\}$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be a 2-dimensional manifold, and $\sigma:I\rightarrow M$ an asymptotic curve such that its curvature as an $\mathbb{R}^3$ curve is never zero.

Consider the basis $\{ T(s),N(s) \}$ of $T_\sigma(s)$ (it is not hard to see that, because $\sigma$ is an asymptotic curve, $N(s)\in T_\sigma(s)$).

I want to compute the determinant of the second fundamental form. I will try to determine the entries $b_{ij}$ of the second fundamental form on this basis. I know that $b_{11}=B(T,T)=0$ because $T$ is an asymptotic direction.
I now want to know $b_{12}=\langle -dN(T),N \rangle=b_{21}$ and $b_{22}=\langle -dN(N),N \rangle$. However, I do not know how the Weingarten map is, so I guess I should determine this in some indirect way.

I was thinking on computing $R_{1212}$, which equals the determinant of the second fundamental form. This would require me to compute the Christoffel symbols, which I can compute because I know the first fundamental form. However, this is computationally demanding. Is there another way?

Comment: You've never used the hypothesis that the curvature of $\sigma$ is everywhere nonzero. Also: I expect that something involving the Frenet-Serret equations will determine the curvature of the surface in terms of the curvature/torsion of $\sigma$.

Comment: You're right: I do not know how I can use it.  
What I am trying to prove is precisely that $K=-\nu^2$. 
I now know that all I have left to do is to prove that $$ b_{12}^2 = \Big(\vec{B}'(s)\Big)^2 = \parallel T(s)\times N(s) \parallel ^2$$
but I do not know how I can do it (and in particular how I can use the hypotheses that I haven't used so far).

Comment: What is $\nu$, please?

Comment: @JohnHughes I should have said that: it is the torsion of $\sigma$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frenet equations say

\begin{align}
T' &= \kappa N\\
N' &= -\kappa T + \nu B \\
B' &= -\nu N
\end{align}

Your last comment says that you want to show $\| B'(s) \|^2$ is ... well, what you wrote is wrong, because you need a prime on $(T(s) \times N(s) )$.

But since $B' = -\nu N$, and $N$ is a unit vector, you get $\|B'\| = \pm \nu$, which should let you finish things up.

Now...why do you need nonzero curvature? To define the Frenet frame at all!

Comment: But it is true that (by definition) $B=T\times N$. This is not what I want to prove. Maybe I explained myself badly. I want to show that $b_{12}^2=B'^2$ so that I can prove that $K=-\nu^2$ or, more rigorously, $K_{\sigma(t)}=-\nu_{\sigma(t)}^2$, where $K$ is the Gauss curvature of the surface.

Comment: Sorry, I see now that I missed the primes.
Still, I would like to prove that $b_{12}^2=B'^2$.
And I think taht what yoiu did is not really an alternative proof, since your $k$ is the curvature of the curve, not the Gauss curvature, right?

Comment: I see. It's that first equality that has you puzzled. Well, I'll go back and look at the definition of $b_{12}$. Notice that the $N$ that you're using in the left side of the inner product  is *not* the curve's normal vector, but the *surface* normal. If we use $n$ to denote that, then you want to compute $\langle dn(T), N \rangle$. Now the surface normal (since the curve's tangent and normal are both in the tangent plane to the surface) is just $B$. How does $B$ change when you move in the $T$ direction? That's just $B'$....

Comment: Ok, so you're saying the following, if I am not mistaken:
$b_{12}=\langle-dn(T),N\rangle=\langle-B',N\rangle=\langle-\parallel B'\parallel N,N\rangle=-\parallel B \parallel$. This indeed yields our result. Just one thing: I learned that the differential was the map such that $dF(v)(h)=v(h\circ F)$. How can I relate this with what you said? That is, I did not understand why $B'=dn$. I understood the intuitive argument, but I am having a hard time understanding how I can make that rigorous.

Comment: I'm going to leave that to you to work out; I need to run off to an appointment.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it: 
Since $B=(n\circ \sigma)$, then
$$
B'(s) = DB(s)(1) = \Big( Dn(\sigma(s))\circ D\sigma(s) \Big)(1) 
\\      = Dn(\sigma(s))\Big(D\sigma(s)(1)\Big) = Dn(\sigma(s))(\sigma'(s))
\\      = Dn(\sigma(s))(T(s))
$$
And I guess that it should be obvious that this is the same as $d_{\sigma(s)}n(T(s))$. However, as I've told you before, the definition that I saw for differential is quite far from this (*i.e.*, it is not clear that it is jsut a generalization of the derivative, or, in the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$, the same thing).